# Books on collision probability and collision processes

Tags: collision, atoms, probability, particle-physics, molecules

Are there any books specifically on collision processes between atoms and molecules and collision probability?

I would like to get an overview of the factors that determine collision probability between particles, like number density, relative velocity, particle size and such.

Comment: Could you give some background?  Are you interested in gases, in high energy collisions of accelerated atoms, or what?  Are you looking for numerical answers, or for mathematical techniques?

Comment: Can you google "atomic collisions" and follow the links?

Comment: Sure I googled. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @akrasia: Accelerated atoms sound interesting. So far I've only read about instantaneous collisions. My interest lies mainly in monoatomic gases, not molecules.